# Detect mobile phone carrier on Blackberry 10 Webworks app

Tags: blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

Is there any way to detect the name of the user's mobile phone carrier in a Blackberry 10 Webworks app? I haven't found anything in the api:

http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/api/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the Mobile Network Code (MNC) value using the following BlackBerry 10 WebWorks extension.

https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/BB10/deviceInfo

The MNC is a numeric value that you can associate with a carrier. For example the MNC of Rogers Wireless (canadian carrier) is 720.  More info here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to check the carrier. But what you can do is deliver different binaries based on the carrier in the App World Vendor Portal.

[image]